# What to do with incorrect information

Tags: discussion, flagging

I recently came across a comment containing incorrect information, and I wasn't sure how to approach it.

Seeing as you cannot downvote comments, I decided to flag it, but there's no 'incorrect' flag, so I listed the flag as 'other' and manually entered 'incorrect'. I also left an additional comment (@commenter) explaining what/why their info was wrong, but that seems to edge into the realm of 'chat' (though in this case it happened to still be somewhat on topic for the question.)

What approach should I/we take to quantifiably incorrect information in our beloved community?

Edit:
[Here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27883/how-to-find-out-if-my-non-fuel-injected-car-has-a-rev-limiter/27885?noredirect=1#comment45096_27885) is the question in.. uh... question. Comments to be found under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can refute it in the comments, or in an answer to the question. If things get to chatty we will move it to chat. Just be respectful when you do it.

Comment: I added the post I was referring to, I think it was respectful enough.

Comment: Yes, totally respectful.  It's a strange issue.  I've typically tried to lure them into chat and have a debate where I ask a million questions and post links to drag them along.  Sometimes, it feels like way too much effort to undumb someone.  Other times, I'm more enthusiastic.  I suppose it's in direct correlation to the amount of passion I have for the subject matter.....but I"m still unsure of how to ultimately handle it to prevent bad info from contaminating the entire planet.....

Answer (score 1):

Comments don't carry much weight here, its up to the OP to use the information or not.

You can comment with a link to refute the misinformation, most will delete the comment after that, and if they do not its obvious they are off base. I have been busted more than once, which made me more careful about my comments.